# Cookies won't reset on iteration in JMeter 'Loop Controller'?

Tags: jmeter

Using Jmeter 2.12, what could cause the cookies to fail to reset during a JMeter Loop Controller?  I've tried everything I can think of, but each time through the loop, one of the cookies from a previous login still remains.   It doesn't seem to actually clear the cookies.

Here is how I put together my loop:

```
Thread Group 1
  -- Loop Controller (3x)
    -- Simple Controller
      -- HTTP Header Manager
      -- HTTP Cookie Manger (with 'Clear cookies each iteration?' enabled)
      -- BeanShell sampler - with code that tries to clear all cookies
      -- HTTP /login (gets cookies and auth headers)
      -- ... various HTTP Samplers ...
      -- HTTP /logout
```

I tried adding a Beanshell sampler with this code (as shown above) but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HeaderManager;

CookieManager cManager = sampler.getCookieManager();
cManager.clear();
HeaderManager hManager = sampler.getHeaderManager();
hManager.clear();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Loop Controller doesn't increment iteration. You can test it by evaluating [vars.getIteration()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getIteration()) Beanshell code line. Iteration is being incremented on Thread Group level. To override this you can call [vars.incIteration()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#incIteration()) method in any Beanshell-enabled Test Element (Sampler, Pre/Post Processor, Assertion, etc.)
2. You Beanshell code for clearing cookies actually does nothing as `cManager` instance isn't being passed back to the sampler. You need to modify your code as follows:

   ```
   CookieManager cManager = sampler.getCookieManager();
   cManager.clear();
   sampler.setCookieManager(cManager);
   ```

   So `sampler` could have that "cManager" instance with cleared cookies

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the iteration variable.

Comment: For anyone running into this, all you should need is the

sampler.getCookieManager().clear();

Answer (score 8):

Ok, I figured out the problem.   Even though the 'HTTP Cookie Manager' has an option called 'Clear cookies each iteration', the 'iteration' it speaks of does not include a Loop Controller.  What it refers to is the 'Thread Group' iterations/loops only.   This was not clear and I wasted half a day until I figured this out.   Wouldn't have been confusing if the checkbox said 'Clear cookies each Thread Group iteration' instead.   Very disappointing.